# How to Stop Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

I use the Phusion Passenger module (mod_passenger) for the Apache HTTP Server and Capistrano for deployment of rails applications.

I want to 'stop' a Ruby on Rails application from Phusion Passenger. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't stop it without editing the Apache config and taking out or commenting out the `VirtualHost` block for the Rails application and then restarting the Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to stop it for good? Edit the apache conf file, change the `DocumentRoot` of the virtual host to *not* point to a Rails installation, then `apachectl graceful`.

If you want to fully start and stop your Rails app via Capistrano, you can write some simple cap tasks that basically do what I outlined above: log in, edit the conf file, and restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
sudo a2dissite
```

Then I wrote the name of the Rails site and hit enter. After that, I reloaded Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```