# Everlasting ruby process

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to kill the ruby process, but it is impossible. I am using Ubuntu, I clean my cache, I reboot my os, then the ruby server is running. But if I run `pgrep -l ruby`, I get some pid I am trying to kill with `kill -9 $pid`. But when I run again `pgrep -l ruby`, it everlastingly showing the same process I want to kill... Someone could help ?

Comment: You probably have some kind of monitoring solution running or you're using a forking solution like unicorn, passenger or resque and you're killing the forked process instead of the main one.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pstree -p | less` and hit `/` to search, rather than `pgrep`. This will show a full tree of processes and how they are created. Destroy the process higher up.

Comment: yes I can see some ruby processes connected to Passenger, but how can I find the pid to kill ? What do you mean by the process higher up ?

Comment: Maybe this is better for you then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838466/how-to-stop-phusion-passenger

Comment: But if you just want to kill passenger, the `-p` flag on `pstree` will show you the PID for passenger. I don't recommend killing it though.

Comment: ok but why is it dangerous to kill it ? (because I can't use mysql anymoire to hear another port, everytime I connect to localhost, I al rediredcted to my rails app)

Comment: What are you using for your server on port 80? Is it apache?

Comment: Did this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838466/how-to-stop-phusion-passenger

Comment: yes I read it, but I was looking for a more simple solution. Stopping the process seemed very simple, so I don't know what to do ...

Comment: Sorry, the entire point of using passenger is to make those processes harder to kill. You'll have to remove the site from apache, or not use passenger, if you want them to not show up.

Answer (score 2):

First use the following command to show the list of running process:

```
ps -l
```

Then it show some process list like

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  2456  1610  2  80   0 - 28987 wait   pts/2    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1000  2512  2456  0  80   0 - 28408 -      pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

Then kill the process by using command:

```
kill -9 PID
```

It always worked for me.

**Edited for your case:**

Use the command:

```
ps -fu username
```

This command shows all the running processes on your system, then you can kill any one of them.